# Bootstrap 3 modal wont remove when I click close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove the ajax requested model when I user either hits close or cancel. I have tried the following.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

full code

```
<div id="registerModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h1 class="text-center">Sign Up</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="register" id="register" action="login" method="post" class="col-md-12 center-block">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4 class="text-center">Business Info</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="businessname" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Business Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="abnacn" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="ABN or ACN" >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="phone" name="phonenumber" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Main Phone Number" >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="busiussemail" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Main Email Address" >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="checkbox" name="TOS" >
                <br>By registering and ticking this box for My Staff, you are agreeing to our TOS and Privacy Policy.
              </div>
              <!--<div class="form-group">
                <select name="buildingtype" class="form-control select-lg">
                  <option value="0">--- none ---</option>
                  <option value="1">Unit</option>
                  <option value="2">Floor</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="unitnumber" name="number" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Unit / Floow Number">
                <input type="streetno" name="number" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="street number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="streetname" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Street Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" name="postcode" class="form-control input-lg login" onkeyup="getLocation()" placeholder="postcode">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="state" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Country" readonly>
              </div>-->


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4 class="text-center">User login set up</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="emailadress" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Admin staff Email Address">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="passwordtwo" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Password Repeat">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="First Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="sirname" class="form-control input-lg login" placeholder="Last Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              </div>
              </div>


              <button typpe="submit" onclick="signupmore();" class="btn btn-success col-md-12 btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your HTML, you have mismatched closing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're manually adding the class 'show' to the modal.

If you remove that, then open the modal in JS you can close it.

http://www.bootply.com/EMWW2UWBtr

```
$('#registerModal').modal('show');

<div id="registerModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
```